# How to pass option id on select in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a select control, and I'd like it to pass the id of the selected option when the option changes, but can't figure out how to do that.

```
<select id="companydropdown" (change)="getcompanyid($event)">
<option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies" value={{company.companyName}} 
id={{company.id}}>
{{company.companyName}}
</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the selected value using "$event.target.value". For that the expected value must be assigned to the "value" property of "" tag.

```
<select id="companydropdown" (change)="getcompanyid($event.target.value)">
  <option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies" value="{{company.id}}">
    {{company.companyName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Notice the changes in event handler and

See the stackblitz for full example: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-option-to-event

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is by using ReactiveFormsModule. First, you need to declare the FormBuilder controllers to set up, then an array of your elements (options), as in this example:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  isSubmitted = false;

  // City Names
  City: any = ['Florida', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Michigan', 'New York']

  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) { }

  /*########### Form ###########*/
  registrationForm = this.fb.group({
    cityName: ['', [Validators.required]]
  })

  // Getter method to access formcontrols
  get cityName() {
    return this.registrationForm.get('cityName');
  }

  /*########### Template Driven Form ###########*/
  onSubmit() {
    this.isSubmitted = true;
    if (!this.registrationForm.valid) {
      return false;
    } else {
      alert(JSON.stringify(this.registrationForm.value))
    }

  }

}
```

Then you can iterate your options at template:

```
<select class="custom-select" (change)="changeCity($event)" formControlName="cityName">
   <option value="" disabled>Choose your city</option>
   <option *ngFor="let city of City" [ngValue]="city">{{city}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's a nice and full tutorial for your needs:
https://www.positronx.io/angular-7-select-dropdown-examples-with-reactive-forms/

Please, also read the documentation to better understand ReactiveForms, maybe it takes some more minutes but worth it: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Answer (score 0):

Pass it where? Like instead of the `companyName`? What gets passed is the option value, you just need to change the value to be the id:

```
<select id="companydropdown" change="getcompanyid($event)">
   <option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies" value={{company.id}} id={{company.id}}>
      {{company.companyName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: the getcompanyid($event) event should send the option id instead of the option value

Comment: You can't really do that. The `(change)` event sends the value of the selected option. You can set the value to anything you want, including the id. The value isn't displayed anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the `id` on the change event handler
`event.currentTarget.options[event.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].id`

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

Component.html

```
<select id="companydropdown" (change)="getcompanyid($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let company of filteredCompanies" value="{{company.id}}">
    {{company.companyName}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Component.ts

```
getcompanyid(e){
    console.log(e.target.value)
}
```